# How to get regions from points in a mask image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, k-means, contour, dilation

Point space:

[image: point space]

Dilated:

[image: dilated]

I used dilation (morphological process) but this is not the result i expected. I want more smooth regions, not squares. How to define contours and fill in them? Maybe i can use k-means like algorithms to het regions from points. Help please.

Comment: point clouds need fundamentally different algorithms than 2d pictures. you just assume that there won't be any points on the ground and that **buildings** are densely populated with points

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the adaptive thresholds. It will help you handle this particular issue.